# Call method with class parameters through reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I've just started out with C# reflection, and I ran into the issue of calling methods that take internal classes as arguments:

Sample class:

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public class CustomColor 
    {
        public int h;
        public int s;
        public int v;
    }

    public string[] ConvertColors(List<CustomColor> colors)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

The code I'm using to call other methods in this class :

```
FieldInfo info = cInstanceContainerObject.GetType().GetField("_myClass", BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
dynamic myClassObject = info.GetValue(cInstanceContainerObject);
```

Allowing me to do this :

```
myClassObject.SomeSampleMethod(int sampleParam);
```

However, I'm stuck on figuring out how to create the proper parameters for the ConvertColors method above. :(

Comment: Do you want to invoke `ConvertColors`?

Comment: @singsuyash yeah, I want to invoke ConvertColors, but I can't get my head around creating instances of CustomColor, then making a List of them and passing that to my invoke.

Comment: would you like an answer that simply invokes using `MethodInfo.Invoke`? Or are you looking for something else.

Comment: I don't mind any method, as long as I can call ConvertColors, without getting "The best overloaded method match for 'MyClass.ConvertColors(System.Collections.Generic.List<MyClass.CustomColor>)' has some invalid arguments" :(

Comment: Please paste how parameter `colors` is instanced now.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you created your `cInstanceContainerObject`. I am using `MethodInfo.Invoke`. Below is the code:

```
//Your class
public class MyClass 
{
    public class CustomColor 
    {
        public int h;
        public int s;
        public int v;
    }

    public string[] ConvertColors(List<CustomColor> colors)
    {
        return new string[]{"1"};
    }
}

//Usage
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
    MyClass.CustomColor cc = new MyClass.CustomColor();

    Type t = mc.GetType();
    MethodInfo mi = t.GetMethod("ConvertColors");
    List<MyClass.CustomColor> lst = new List<MyClass.CustomColor>
    {   
        new MyClass.CustomColor(),
        new MyClass.CustomColor()
    };
    var x = (string[])mi.Invoke(mc,new object[]{lst});
    Console.WriteLine (x.Count());
```

Comment: The instance comes from another DLL. When I try to add it as a reference and use the same List<MyClass.CustomColor>, I get an "unkown exception while invoking dynamic method"

Comment: is `cInstanceContainerObject` and instance of `MyClass` or `CustomColor`?

Answer (score 0):

Tom,

Try passing the color you wish to convert as a reference.

In the example below, the color (CustomColor) you pass in as a reference will be updated, instead of returning strings.

So, instead of calling the method like:

```
string[] colors = ConvertColors(yourColorList, foo, bar);
```

it can instead be called as:

```
ConvertColors(yourColorList, foo, bar);
```

Example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public class CustomColor
    {
        public int h;
        public int s;
        public int v;
    }

    public enum Convert { H, S, V, HS, HV, SV, HSV };

    public void ConvertColors(ref List<CustomColor> colors, Convert type,
        ref CustomColor changeAmt)
    {
        // Variables to change H, S, and V from changeAmt parameter:
        int changeH = changeAmt.h;
        int changeS = changeAmt.s;
        int changeV = changeAmt.v;

        // Change the actual colors which were passed as 'colors' parameter.
        switch (type)
        {
            // Change H.
            case Convert.H:
                foreach (CustomColor c in colors)
                    c.h += changeH;
                break;

            // Change S.
            case Convert.S:
                foreach (CustomColor c in colors)
                    c.s += changeS;
                break;

            // Change V.
            case Convert.V:
                foreach (CustomColor c in colors)
                    c.v += changeV;
                break;

            // Change HS.
            case Convert.HS:
                foreach (CustomColor c in colors)
                {
                    c.h += changeH;
                    c.s += changeS;
                }
                break;

            // Change HV.
            case Convert.HV:
                foreach (CustomColor c in colors)
                {
                    c.h += changeH;
                    c.v += changeV;
                }
                break;

            // Change SV.
            case Convert.SV:
                foreach (CustomColor c in colors)
                {
                    c.s += changeS;
                    c.v += changeV;
                }
                break;

            // Change HSV.
            case Convert.HSV:
                foreach (CustomColor c in colors)
                {
                    c.h += changeH;
                    c.s += changeS;
                    c.v += changeV;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Explanation:

'enum' allows you to create a custom parameter for your method:

```
public enum Convert { H, S, V, HS, HV, SV, HSV };
```

the 'switch' statement allows you to handle those parameters:

```
switch (type)
        {
            case Convert.H:
                // Do something
                return;
            case Convert.S:
                // Do something
                return;
            case Convert.V:
                // Do something
                return;
```

Create an instance of the changes you want to make as a new CustomColor, and pass a reference to the list of CustomColors, your custom parameter, and a reference to the changes as a CustomColor:

```
private void AnyMethod()
    {
        // Create first custom color.
        CustomColor color1 = new CustomColor();
        color1.h = 50;
        color1.s = 25;
        color1.v = 35;

        // Create second custom color.
        CustomColor color2 = new CustomColor();
        color2.h = 50;
        color2.s = 25;
        color2.v = 35;

        // Create third custom color.
        CustomColor color3 = new CustomColor();
        color3.h = 50;
        color3.s = 25;
        color3.v = 35;

        // Add to list of custom colors.
        List<CustomColor> colorList = new List<CustomColor>();
        colorList.Add(color1);
        colorList.Add(color2);
        colorList.Add(color3);

        // Create changes as a new color.
        CustomColor colorChange = new CustomColor();
        colorChange.h = -10;
        colorChange.s = 47;
        colorChange.v = -15;

        // Update all colors in your list.
        ConvertColors(ref colorList, Convert.HSV, ref colorChange); // BOOM.
    }
```

If you wish to get the strings afterwards:

```
string[] hsvStrings =
        {
            color1.h.ToString(),
            color1.s.ToString(),
            color1.v.ToString(),
            // Continue...
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

After a sleepless night I actually figured out how to achieve this. Both answers did help me see the possibilities that led me to the answer, however I had to achieve this without referencing the foreign DLL, or doing any modifications to it, just get an instance of it's main object through Reflection, and then call the various methods within it (some of which required classes only provided by the DLL itself as you can see in my example).

My solution is like this (feel free to provide better alternatives) :

Get a Type of both the List and CustomColor each, by utilizing the method parameter:

```
Type listType = myClassObject.GetType()
                             .GetMethod("ConvertColors")
                             .GetParameters()[0]
                             .ParameterType;

Type colorType = myClassObject.GetType()
                 .GetMethod("ConvertColors")
                 .GetParameters()[0]
                 .ParameterType
                 .GetProperty("Item")
                 .PropertyType;
```

Then create individual instances of both the entire list and individual CustomColors using Activator:

```
dynamic colorList = Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
dynamic customColor = Activator.CreateInstance(colorType);
colorList.Add(customColor);

myClassObject.ConvertColors(colorList); //works!
```